# error while installing modules in openerp 6.1

Tags: odoo

I have fresh openerp 6.1 and trying to install existing modules(like sale, purchase etc) but while installing it gives error "yaml_interpreter = YamlInterpreter(cr, module, idref, mode, filename=yamlfile.name, noupdate=noupdate) AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'name'". I doesn't understand why this error to existed modules. anyone can help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of python you are using ?

Comment: Thanks Parthiv, for replying. I have solved this problem. There was a existed error in openerp modules which i am going to install. I have tried with another setup of openerp and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You may solve this as follows

1) In line 191 in the file server/openerp/tools/misc.py change

`from cStringIO import StringIO`

to

`from StringIO import StringIO`

2) After line 124 in the file server/openerp/modules/loading.py
   add line

```
fp.name = filename
```